# Lorentz force on superconductors?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

If current flows on the surface of a superconductor(for both type I & II) and is exposed to an exterior magnetic field, will a superconductor experience a Lorentz force?

Knowing that a superconductor expels the magnetic field from the interior of the material:

[image]

It seems that the magnetic field interacts with the surface charges?

Comment: Yes, the superconductor will experience a force, just like a normal conductor would. In a superconductor the current only flows in a thin skin and the magnetic field will enter into the superconductor in this skin volume, so there is an interaction region for the Lorentz force. In general, though, it is easier to calculate the forces by calculating the gradient of the total energy of the resulting magnetic field.

Comment: Very nice question. One has to consider, how the Cooper paired electrons with their anti-aligned magnetic dipole moments are influenced by an external magnetic field. Any links to performed experiments and the results are welcome.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm comparing the differences, I believe to achieve a greater Lorentz force superconductors would be far superior than regular conductors correct?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Indeed, however, in theory it seems reasonable and logical that such a force would exist, I wish I could experiment on it,but sadly it's not feasible for me to discover.

Comment: No, it's all the same, which follows from energy conservation.

Comment: @CuriousOne What do you mean the same? Magnitude of force? That makes sense, but a $x$ $cm^3$ of a superconducting material has the ability to withstand higher current's(therefore greater forces) than the same $x$ $cm^3$ of copper of that makes sense?

Comment: One can actually achieve much higher fields with copper magnets than with superconductors because superconductors have a critical field beyond which they stop working, while metals do not have that problem. The required power simply goes up with the square of the magnetic field, so it's an expensive proposition to run such a high field magnet facility.